# Database Structure for like in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am new in Laravel, I want to have like button on my website

**My Post Table:**

```
    post_id    |    body    |    created_at
```

**My like table:**

```
    like_id    |   user_id  |     post_id    | timestamp
```

---

**Questions:**

1-How to count likes in Laravel?

2-Is my database structure true or not?

3-I am going to have reputation (Like stackoverflow), Should I save that republication in one field in **user** table or it has different structure?

Comment: Do you mean *reputation*?

Comment: @lukasgeiter oh yes reputation

Comment: @lukasgeiter can you please answer to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can count results with Laravel using `count()` method. For
   example to count all likes in the table:

   ```
   // Eloquent + Query Builder
   $likes = Likes::all()->count();

   // Query Builder
   $likes = DB::table('likes')->count();
   ```

You might want to look at the [aggregation methods Laravel offers](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#aggregates).

2. The structure of the two tables you showed looks fine. One thing to consider is what should happen to respective likes when a user or a post gets deleted (`ON DELETE ...`)
3. You could put reputation field in the `user` table, but the cleaner way
   to do it is to create separate table for reputation with a foreign
   key to user ID.

Answer (score 1):

I would add the total like count to the post table as well. If you don't add it you need to perform sum() queries all the time, which might put too much load on your database (depending on the numver of visits on your site, etc).

You can save the reputation in the user table. You probably want to add something like your like table though. Users for sure want to know why they received some more reputation.